# Is it possible to use a single JAXBContext for all requests in a Spring-WS endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, jax-ws, spring-ws

I'm writing a simple spring-ws webservice which implements a WSDL that was defined by another project. The problem is that this WSDL and the related datatypes are extremely complicated and when sending a request to the webservice it takes around 15 seconds to initialise the JAXBContext and spring seems to create a new JAXBContext for each incoming datatype. The relevant spring code is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/method/jaxb/AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java#L227).

Given that I can't change the datatypes, is it possible to change the JAXBContext initialisation strategy used by spring-ws? Ideally, I'd just need the single JAXBContext cached for all requests as I can be certain that the context will be the same across requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by accepting and responding with org.w3c.dom.Elements and having a singleton bean with a single JAXBContext which can convert between the JAXBElements and Elements.